# Is there a way to handle application session timeout for parallel selenium test execution?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application which needs a userid password login. I am currently automating its test scenarios using selenium and java and need those tests to run in parallel. I have created one userid for automation tests. But when i run them in parallel i get a session timeout error for random tests and execution fails.

My chromedriver initiation is thread safe, so that cannot be the problem

Talking with the dev of the application, i came to know that same user login simultaneously is not allowed and previous open session receives a timeout error. I have even tried opening them in incognito, but that doesnt help. SO currently i believe, that for parallel execution: 
Create the number of users i need to run parallel and give each test class its independent userid.

Is there any other way to handle this scenario? I think it will always be cumbersome to create several user ids for automation testing.

Comment: Share your attemps that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the one set of cookies for all your webdriver instances. To do that, create variable "Set cookies" that will be accessed from all threads.

For example, if you use a superclass to inherit all your test classes, add the static variable to the superclass.

On login action, check if the variable is null. If true - log in and get cookies from webdirver. If false, set cookies to webdriver without log in action.

```
Set<Cookie> cookies;
cookies =webDriver.manage().getCookies();
cookies.forEach( cookie -> webDriver.manage().addCookie( cookie ) );
```

Comment: will try this.. but will this also work when i have four parallel logins... all four might end up saying cookies = null. this will occur for only the first run. maybe i should execute one single tc at the start to set cookies and then run remaining on 4 threads? any thought?

Comment: For example, you may extend set to Map<Credentials, Set<Cookies>>